# Is there a way other than eval to prevent my perl scripts from terminating on errors

Tags: perl

I am coding a web API that uses a MongoDB database, interacts with node.js and starts all types of processes, anything can go wrong and if it does I want the api to return an "unknown error" message to the caller.

The problem is that sometimes the modules I'm using crash and the whole application dies without giving the api the opportunity to return an "Unknown error" message I want to control this without having to put an eval block in every database insert, process call, etc.

is there something like autoeval ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your process is crashing, something is very wrong, and you should look into why that is and fix it.

But failing that, do all your work in a child process, and have the parent monitor it and return an error response.

Though even easier than that is running your service behind a proxy server (which you may very well be doing anyway) and ensuring that the proxy server returns an appropriate api response on proxy errors.

Comment: I am still logging the errors I just dont want the person calling the API seeing them. The proxy is a good idea, I dont do the child process monitoring idea because I am using Mojolicious web framework which already uses preforking